# Problems due to analyzing variables from different levels at one single level

Tags: regression, inference, sample-size, multilevel-analysis, misspecification

Please ease the following paragraph from the first chapter , Introduction to Multilevel Analysis , [p.3 of the book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848728468):

> Historically , multilevel problems have led to analysis approaches that moved all variables by aggregation or disaggregation to one single level of interest followed by an ordinary multiple regression , analysis of variance , or some other 'standard' analysis method . However , analyzing variables from different levels at one single common level is inadequate , and leads to two distinct types of problems .
>
> The first problem is statistical .
>
> If data are aggregated , the result is that different data values from many sub-units  are combined into fewer values for fewer higher-level units . As a result , much information is lost, and the statistical analysis loses power .
>
> On the other hand , if data are disaggregated , the result is that a few data values from a small number of super-units are 'blown up' into many more values for a much larger number of sub-units . Ordinary statistical tests treat all these disaggregated data values as independent information from the much larger sample of sub-units . The proper sample size for these variables is of course the number of higher level units . Using the larger number of disaggregated  cases for the sample size leads to significance tests that reject the null-hypothsis far more often than the nominal alpha level suggests . In other words : investigators come up with many 'significant' results that are totally spurious .

#### EDIT : My question is ,

(1)  In aggregation , how is information lost ? And how do we loose statistical power ?

(2) In disaggregation , how does the issue of sample size occur ? Do they mean if we use the sample size of lower level when we do actually need to use the sample size of higher level , then the sample size becomes large which increases the chance of rejecting the true null hypothesis ?

Comment: [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19800158) is a paper demonstrating what can happen---misleading conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19800158) is a paper which demonstrates what can happen when all variables are analyzed on the same level. One can end up with the wrong conclusions. The simplest way to investigate this s to simulate some simple data, where variables on different levels have effects on a response variable in different directions. [Red State Blue State](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691143935) is a book-length example of this importance.

Below is some simple R code to simulate simple data giving an example. You can just play with code, which should be self-explaining.

```
expit <- function(x) 1/(1+exp(-x))  
gen_mix_data <- function(n_groups=100, group_size=50, alpha=-0.8, beta=0.3, constant=-0.3) {
    gamma <- rep(rnorm(n_groups), rep(group_size, n_groups)) # random effects
    px <- expit(alpha*gamma)
    x <- rbinom(n_groups*group_size, 1, px)
    py <- expit(constant+gamma + beta*x)
    y <- rbinom(n_groups*group_size, 1, py)
    data.frame(x=x, y=y, group=as.factor(rep(1:n_groups, rep(group_size, n_groups))))
}

set.seed(7*11*13)
simdata <- gen_mix_data()

library(lme4)  

mod1 <- glmer(y ~ x + (1 | group), data=simdata, family=binomial())

mod0 <- glm(y ~ x, data=simdata, family=binomial)
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

One example of loss of information when we aggregate is Simpson's paradox, in which we can see a different result altogether.

**2.**

Imagine breaking up a group into 20 partitions randomly; maybe one of them might randomly turn up to be [significant](https://xkcd.com/882/).

As an extreme case if you break up your points which happen to be leverage points, this can lead to interesting behaviour.